# AJAX POST Request to Express Server from PHP Webpage (Same or Different Ports)?

Tags: javascript, express, web

I want to send a POST request through AJAX from a website to an express server when a button is clicked. When I run the server on the same port as the website (localhost:8080), the website no longer renders and I receive a message that states, "Cannot GET /mogle/income.php," "mogle/income.php" being the webpage I want to send the request from. When I run the server on a different port (localhost:8000), the AJAX POST call no longer works. From my current understanding, you can only send requests to different ports using JSONP, but JSONP can only work with GET requests, and I need to use POST.

I've tried putting a app.get function in my server.js file (see code snippet below) to address the webpage not rendering when the server runs on the same port as the website, but when I go to "localhost:8080/mogle/income.php", the file downloads instead of rendering, which I believe is because it's a PHP file and not an HTML file. However, even if this were to work, would I then have to make an app.get statement for every single other webpage (homepage.php, login.php, etc.) on the website in the server.js file?

```js
app.get("/mogle/income.php", (req, res) => {
  // "../../" because the server file is in two folders
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, "../../income.php"));
});

app.post("/path", async (req, res) => {
  // Process response
});
```

What is the convention for sending requests (both POST and GET) from websites to servers in terms of ports?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution could be as below**

- first need to allow all these POST/GET/PUT request on your server, by
  updating the header values

  ```
  const express = require('express')
  const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
  const app = express()

  app.use(bodyParser.json());
  app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}) );

  app.all("/*", function(req, res, next){
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type, Authorization, Content-Length, X-Requested-With');
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,PUT,POST,DELETE,OPTIONS');
    next();
  });

  app.post('/yourendpoint', function (req, res) {
    res.send(req.body)
  })

  app.listen(8080, function () {
    console.log('Server Listening on - localhost:8080!')
  })
  ```

**And in your client side post the data as follows (Angular Example)**

```
let myDataObj = { name: "test", age: 22 , otherprop: "my post data values"};
this.http.post('http://localhost:8080/yourendpoint', JSON.stringify(myDataObj), {
  headers: headers
})
.subscribe(data => {
  console.log(data);
});
```